# VS Code showing problem "The type <classname> is already defined"

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, error-handling

In the problems panel in VS Code i keep getting "The type  is already defined" this error message. But when I open the file the error disappears.

I know this is not an issue but the red marks bothers my eyes.
These error messages may be due to same class, as every file is saved in same folder, I dont know.

Is there a solution to fix all in once.

[image]

Comment: Did you try disabling the warning?

Comment: disabling the warnings did not fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all of the classes are in the same folder, there may be duplicate classes. Thus, place all the different project classes within the different folders may solve the problem.